# Search multiple domains with material-ui autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using material-ui / autoComplete with reactjs.
Searching in a single area. How do I make it search multiple domains.

So I want to add the customerSurname field as well.

Searching on the customerName field. How can I search the CustomerSurname and customerIdentityNo fields?

https://ibb.co/qMjNz1d

```
 <Autocomplete
      id={'customer-search'}
      options={this.state.customerItems}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.customerName}
      renderOption={(option) => (
        <React.Fragment>
          <span> {option.customerIdentityNo}, </span>
          <span> {option.customerName} {option.customerSurname} </span>
        </React.Fragment>
      )}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          label="Search input"
          margin="normal"
          variant="outlined"
          InputProps={{
            ...params.InputProps,
            type: 'search'
          }}
        />
      )}
    />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have combined options, the only way I found is create an array of all values you want in `options`. Something like:

```
<Autocomplete
      id={'customer-search'}
      options={this.state.customerItems.map((option) => return option.customerIdentityNo + "," + option.customerName + "," option.customerSurname)}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.customerName}
      renderOption={(option) => (
        <React.Fragment>
          <span> {option.split(",")[0]}, </span>
          <span> {option.split(",")[1]} {option.split(",")[2]} </span>
        </React.Fragment>
      )}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          label="Search input"
          margin="normal"
          variant="outlined"
          InputProps={{
            ...params.InputProps,
            type: 'search'
          }}
        />
      )}
    />
```

In this way you are creating an option as a string. Then on `renderOption` you could split this string and show element in custom way.

Comment: https://ibb.co/CJsZs3Q
yes it worked. But the name and surname started to come together.

Comment: Yes unfortunately this is the side effect. I didn't found any other way to have multiple options on single `AutoComplete`. Sorry to not be more helpful.

Comment: mate made the fix. with the current code but how can I search in the second field

Answer (score 2):

You could use a library like [fuse.js](https://fusejs.io/) to perform searching on any fields that are in your collection. They have a [demo page](https://fusejs.io/demo.html) where you can try it out.

You would however have to figure out how to integrate with the autocomplete library you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little bit old, but I found myself in the same situation and starting from the most-voted answer I came up with the following code, basically, you can search for whatever is in the label:

```
<Autocomplete
    id="employee_select"
    options={profesionalData}
    getOptionLabel={(option) =>
        `${option.dni || "DNI"} - ${option.name || "-"}`
    }
    isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) =>
        option.name === value.name ? option.name : "-"
    }
    onChange={(event, newValue) => {
        if (!newValue) {
            cleanFields(newValue);
        }
        setProfesionalValue(newValue);
    }}
    inputValue={profesionalInputValue}
    onInputChange={(event, newInputValue) => {
        setProfesionalInputValue(newInputValue);
    }}
    value={profesionalValue ? profesionalValue : ""}
    renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
            {...params}
            label={t("pr_type_form_lbl_employee_select")}
            variant="outlined"
        />
    )}
/>
```